# Passing various values for a textarea as array but only detects the original textareas and NOT the loaded via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery

I've a backend website where the user can add textareas in a section and later I save all the $_POST["array[]"] in the database.

My actual HTML code is:

```
<textarea class="context" name="context[]"></textarea>
<textarea class="context" name="context[]"></textarea>
<textarea class="context" name="context[]"></textarea>
```

If I post this I get 3 results for context. My problem is when I load via AJAX. The exact view that my PHP loads is:

```
<textarea class="context" name="context[]"></textarea>
```

And I see how in firebug is loaded and is exactly like the above. My loader code is:

```
$("a#add-conx").live("click", function(){
    $("#ajax-loader").fadeIn('normal');

    $.ajax({
        url: BASE_URL + 'projects/ajax/get_textarea',
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            $("textarea.context:last").after(data);
        }
    });

    $("#ajax-loader").fadeOut("normal");

    return false;
});
```

And it works fine because it adds exactly next to the last context. But when I post it, i only get results for the first and not for the ajax-loaded ones.

Anyone knows why?

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE**:

When the page is load:
[image]

After adding some content dynamically:
[image]

Code that actually I'm using:

```
$("a#add-conx").click(function(){
    $("#ajax-loader").fadeIn('normal');

    $("textarea.context:last").after('<textarea class="context" name="context[]"></textarea>');

    $("#ajax-loader").fadeOut("normal");

    return false;
});
```

And when I get the $_POST["context"] I ONLY get the first 4 textareas, the ones that I've not created. Why???

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form was not closed... Closing the various forms with `</form>` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't read your full code since ooeramini sort of cuts out the rest of it.

Anyway, are you certain the loaded fields are being loaded inside the form tags? They could be outside leading to their data not being passed. Try a dom source view by highlighting and reading selection source.

Comment: Hello! I've added a images showing how they are added. Just next to the last textarea.content. Yes, I've various forms and differents submits on that page but if they're above the other contents[], they have to work, no??

Comment: Well, that should work. I'm at a loss. An online example should be best.

Answer (score 0):

Just for adding a textarea to dom you should not use ajax...Its a waste of valuable bandwith and time.. There is no need to contact server since you do no need any data fromn there....... just use document.createElement("textarea") or a jquery shortcut for the same for creating textarea....

Comment: This is not the problem but thank you. I'm using AJAX because sometimes I need to pass localitzation text with the template. Thank you!